# Confusing error in PHP code

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have the following PHP code, and the error that I get when I try to run it, says that there is an unexpected EOF error on line 33, which is the final line with the `</html>` tag on it. I have checked for any extra spaces, and there are none. I cannot figure out what the error might be.

```
<body>
<?php
$numOfTeams = " ";

    if($numOfTeams > 2)
    {
        include($numOfTeams);
    }

    $results = $query->fetchAll();
?>

<table align="center" border="1px" style="width: 300px" color="black">
<th>Club Name</th>    <th>Number of Teams</th>
<tr>
    <?php
    while($row = $query->fetch()) {?>
    <td><?php echo $row['cid']; ?></td>
    ?>
</tr>  
<tr>
    <?php
    while($row = $query->fetch()) {?>
    <td><?php echo $row['numOfTeams'];?></td>
    ?>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure why there is an error on that line since from what I can see, there is no actual code on that line.

Comment: You are simply not closing the `while` loops.. In the future use the alternative style for loops and conditions inside HTML code.

Comment: Try not to miss semicolons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Its not a semicolon @TrippKinetics, its a right curly brace being missed after the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

you forget to close `}` of while loops

use this better:

```
<?php
while($row = $query->fetch()) 
{
  echo '<td>' . $row['cid'] . '</td>';
}

while($row = $query->fetch()) 
{
 echo '<td>' . $row['numOfTeams'] . '</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing your bracers correctly and you have a hanging empty closing php tag...

```
<tr>
    <?php
    while($row = $query->fetch()) {?>      <-- Bracer never closed
    <td><?php echo $row['cid']; ?></td>
    ?>                                     <-- Hanging php closing tag
</tr>
```